# Search according to language

Tags: i18n-l10n, search, 7

We are using 3 different languages by multilingual module. If we search by the English word, then search content should be in English, and if we search by Marathi/Hindi word, then search content should be in that particular language.

How can I perform multilingual specific search?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same requirements, and I used the [Custom search](https://drupal.org/project/custom_search) module, which includes a submodule called **Custom Search Internationalization** : "*search content from all or current language only, and all label and selectors translation handling*" (note this module provides also several other helpful features like custom search blocks). Works perfectly.